# How can I force/cause an error or hung job in a print queue

Tags: printing, windows-server-2003-r2

I am currently trying to design a powershell script to check if any of the printers attached to a Win Server 2003R2 have jobs stuck in the queue. so far I am doing:

```
Get-WmiObject -class "win32_printer" | ft shareName, queued, printerState, printerStatus
```

but I need to see how the results change when there is a problem. Short of just waiting until the next time I hear there is a job stuck in the queue, can anyone suggest a way to force an error? What I am looking to catch with this script is those issues wherein a job gets stuck with an error and the whole queue stops, so if I could cause that, it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Quite Simple, setup a printer that doesn't exist as a network printer that points to nowhere using the windows add hardware wizard.  Then print stuff to it.